# Save byte string to varchar column in database

Tags: python, django

Below is the contents of a tuple:

```
('g\xba\xfc\x995m\x9a\xf0\x1d\x8b4f1\x05\xdel\xc8;\x10\xffl\xfd{\xc7MA!\x90\xe5N
\xf9\x98\xf80\xe0wu\x82B\xb5\xc6\xb1T\\Px_\xfarT\x04\xd4\xe1\xfb?\x81\xa2M\x94P\
xa6\x89bM\x00\x18Q\xf7\x979\xd4V\xc5=\xc6\xff.\xf4\x857\t\xdd\xb0\xe4\xda\x1b8\x
b6T\xfbK\x0c\xd4\xc8\x99\xd0\r\xfd\x18\xcfd\x15C\xfaF)\xacuAU\xeb\xb2\xa6\xd9\xb
5-\xa6[\xad6\x17\x13\xe5\xeeqnR"7\xbc\x93\x99\x07H\xbe\nG\x9ejR\xe8\xb5\xdc\xb7\
x93\xc5\x15\'\x95\xb7k\x89\x9d\x04G\xfe\x11\xfa\x0f\x18u\x90v,[\x80_\x93\x0f\xec
\x8cX0\xc7e\xd4\x10\xb7\x89\xe23y\xebo\x06\x11/\x01\x17\xc5U\x87\xbd\xfc\xa6\xbd
\x05\xcb\x9fOWNP\xe8zB`"\x9b\xbf\x0c\xaa\x9b\xfe\x95\x0f\xf5\x81f\x04\xa4c\xae\x
f8\x11\xd6\xcaL\xcf\xd2ZCJ\xcc\x94e\xc3Q_\x8c\xa7\x12\xe3F\xdc\x08*\x98f\xac\x99
\xdf\x0ey\x1dy',)
```

It is a byte string which I would like to convert to a string and insert into the database(mysql) and then also convert back to a byte string.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's an arbitrary byte string, you should use something like [base64](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html) to convert it to text:

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode(byteString)
# Now insert "encoded" into the database
```

Then:

```
import base64
# Retrieve encoded from the database...
byteString = base64.b64decode(encoded)
```

You should *not* just try to treat it as encoded text unless it really *is* encoded text.

Alternatively, if you're in control of the database schema, you should consider changing the table to use a binary-oriented column instead of a text-oriented one.

Comment: Thanks Jon, it worked, I've spent days on this! Just out of interest is it possible to convert it to a string in it's original format i.e. g\xba\xfc\x995m...... and then decode it as a byte?

Comment: @Imran: If you mean "in Python escaping form" then it may be, but I don't know how - and it won't be as easily portable if you ever want to read the data from another language.